# What is the vb6 IXMLDOMNode equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, xml, vb6, msxml, xmlnode

What is the C# equivalent of 
`Public Function getXMLNode() As MSXML.IXMLDOMNode`?

Here is a  [vb6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example where IXMLDOMNode is used to get the XML from the node.

Here is a [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd893260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example where IXMLDOMNODE is used. However, when I write
 `public IXMLDOMNode getXMLNode()` 
 I get the: **type or namespace name IXMLDOMNODE could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)**
 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the XMLDOM sdk: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4608

Comment: According to this example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw.aspx XMLNode can do the same thing? I am still testing it though.

Comment: Sure! In fact, I would recommend using the native .net libraries. Thought you _needed_ the one in your question.